# How do I get an Image.network to show a different image if a variable is null

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

[image: Code]
How do I show a different image if a _readProfile is null

I tried the picture above and it is erroring out

Comment: can you include sode-snippet instead of code-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a method with return `Widget`.

And it will work as below

```
  Widget getImage() {
    if (_readProfile != null) {
      return Image.network('YOUR LINK');
    } else {
      return Image.asset('URL FROM ASSET FOLDER');
    }
  }
```

Then you just need to call this method

```
Container(
  child: getImage(),
)
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line by using ?? - if null operator

```
Image.network(_readProfile?.image.toString() ?? 'Your link')
```

Answer (score 0):

add a default image in you app
for exemple

```
const String _defaultImage =
    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQK_rZWRT_RXyeRBWmGHQB52XAdSfSFFbIMHyCqWZ0&s";
```

now you can use it in Image.network

```
Image.network(
        a ?? _defaultImage,           
      ),
```

and you can add a default icon if the error will come from the server

```
 Image.network(
        a ?? _defaultImage,
        errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => const Icon(Icons.person)),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use errorBuilder property:

```dart
Image.network(
      "Image URL",
      errorBuilder: (context, error,_){
        return Image.asset("Image URL");
      },
    );
```